# Rolling back the Gap theory question

Tags: discussion, editing, specific-question

[Can the two aspects of the Gap Theory be Biblically Undermined](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/32914/6071)

The OP originally asked for the basis *for* two aspects of the Gap theory, but then also said they'd welcome answers going the other way. I removed that so that it's only asking for one perspective.

@Onlyheisgood then made an edit suggestion reversing it to ask for the basis against it. I voted against the edit, but because FMShyanguya edited it, it got approved anyway.

Anyone got any good arguments why it shouldn't be rolled back to [revision 4](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/revisions/32914/4)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, that edit was totally inappropriate.

If it had ever preserved the "both sides" aspect of the original we might have discussed whether the subject matter was small enough to deal with it that way, but instead he completely reversed it.

Looking at the material out there it looks like the issue is way too complex to deal with except one view at a time anyway, so I've restored your edit. Nice clean up job by the way.